# Is it okay to store the logged in user in the session in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm very new to RoR, and am trying to implement a user login system. I've got most of it working, but I'm trying to work out how I refer to the logged in user across many different views/controllers etc. Can I store the user in the session? Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would more likely store the user id in the session, then get the actual user from somewhere else, like your datastore. That said, there are [plugins](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html) to do authentication already, and you wouldn't need to worry about any of this if you used one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Using something like Authlogic or Devise is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a newbie, do checkout Rails Tutorial - http://www.railstutorial.org/book. There's a chapter that covers login/logout/sign up stuffs.